# Firebase Error - net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am facing a strange issue with trying to update Firebase database. The following error is thrown on the chrome developer console:

I am facing a strange issue with trying to update Firebase database. The following error is thrown on the chrome developer console:

[image]

This issue happens only from the UAE Region. So I think it's because the network operator has blacklisted this URL

`s-usc1c-nss-109.firebaseio.com`

My question is:

Is there a way I can tell the firebase API to use a different server for database ?

Answer (score 0):

*firebaser here*

There is no API to control which domain name your Firebase Database is served from.